# Динамически поменять структуру верстки, через JS

Tags: javascript

подскажите как реализовать динамическую замену структуры html, при смене разрешения.
Нашел наглядный пример, там при разрешении 1365 подставляется новый класс, и новая структура.
сайт главная страница divan.ru раздел Популярные категории. Там слайдер меняет структуру при адаптиве.
Подскажите кто сталкивался по подобным, как это реализовать через js [image: введите сюда описание изображения]?